# Tensorflow: swap iterators without reinitialising during epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, iterator, tensorflow-datasets

I have split my data-set up to 4/5 training and 1/5 test. Currently, I'm using a reinitialisable iterator to swap from training data to validation data at the end of a training epoch. This means that I have a strange step like validation curve in  my tensorboard summaries. Is there a way of running 4 steps of training then 1 step of the validation set without having to reinitialise the iterator and reset the progress through each of the data-sets?

Comment: Use a **feedable iterator**. It allows you to select which iterator you want to get your data from without having to reinitialize anything. See the example in [Creating an iterator](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#creating_an_iterator).

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Perfect! Thank you!